# SSH error on Linux : Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am getting this error

> Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/my_user/.ssh/known_hosts).
>
> my_user@the_server.com: Permission denied (publickey).

I struggle to figure out why I am getting it.

Comment: Check the file permissions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37164/ssh-and-home-directory-permissions

Comment: Thks that's what I put in my answer indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files should be owned by the user trying to connect.

So in my case I had to use an admin user to  do

```
sudo chown my_user config
sudo chown my_user id_rsa
sudo chown my_user id_rsa.pub
sudo chown my_user known_hosts
```

Comment: Hey, FYI, sudo chown username {config,id_rsa,id_rsa.pub,known_hosts} would have saved you a few keystrokes.